# SAS: "Export to Excel" option not appearing in right-click menu in Results Viewer window

Tags: microsoft-excel

Back in the day (as in last year), I was able to right-click on a table from the output in the Results Viewer window and get a menu that included an "Export to Excel" or "Open in Excel" option. Selecting this menu option would launch Excel and open the table in it. After updating my OS from Win7 to Win10, and re-installing SAS (9.4), I no longer see this option in the right-click menu.

I have a vague memory of needing to actively turn this utility on in some previous installation, but I have no idea what the steps were (or if I even really had to do this).

Any help or ideas?

Comment: Which SAS product are you using? You'll note that the SAS tag you've used is for the storage system SAS, not the big data software publisher SAS.

Comment: Oops. SAS, the statistical software.